# show that $(X,d )\ $ is compact .

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

if every proper closed subset of a metric space $(X,\ d)\ $  is finite.

show that $(X,d )\ $ is compact .

how to show ?? by definition or by some equivalent criteria. Any hint

Comment: Just use the open cover definition, it's very easy.

Comment: Start with an arbitrary open cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}$. Take any finite subset of this cover, say $U_{\alpha_1}, \ldots, U_{\alpha_N}$ that covers at least one point of $X$. Then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}U_{\alpha_n}$ is an open set, so its complement is closed, hence finite. So you only need finitely many additional $U_{\alpha}$ to cover the complement.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be an open cover of $X$. Fix a $\lambda_0\in\Lambda$ such that $A_{\lambda_0}\neq\emptyset$. Then $X\setminus A_{\lambda_0}$ is a proper closed subset of $X$ and therefore it is finite. So $X\setminus A_{\lambda_0}=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$. For each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, let $\lambda_k\in\Lambda$ be such that $x_k\in A_{\lambda_k}$. Then$$\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_{\lambda_k}$$and therefore$$X=\bigcup_{k=0}^nA_{\lambda_k}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Extra credit:**  Show that $X$ is actually finite.

**Proof:**  If $X$ is empty or has only one point, fine.  Otherwise choose two points $x$ and $y$.  Since $X$ is a metric space, it is Hausdorff, so the two points have disjoint open neighborhoods. Conclude those open neighborhoods are finite.  Hence $x$ is an isolated point. We have now shown every point is isolated.  Again, choose a point $x$.  Then $\{x\}$ is an open set, hence its complement is finite.

We only used that the space is Hausdorff.  So:

> **Proposition:**  Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space in which every proper closed set is finite.  Then $X$ is finite.

Comment: I find the perverse incentives on MSE bothersome.  The original post is evidently a rather easy homework problem, so it is better not to give complete solutions, only a hint.  But since a complete solution was already given, ...

Comment: Maybe better for the OP's learning experience, but not necessarily better for the wider audience of MSE. This answer is a great example showing that even routine homework questions can yield interesting answers. (+1)